# How to install yeoman 0.9.6

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I work on a application build with node.js and yeoman 0.9.6 but yeoman 1.0 is slightly different and not compatible with the application and I can't migrate it to yeoman 1.0

So I unsuccessfully tried to find a way to install yeoman 0.9.6 (Linux)

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, installing the 0.9.x of Yeoman is no longer officially supported. We provide a brief [Migration Guide](http://yeoman.io/migrate.html) to move from 0.9 to the new 1.0 architecture.

You can still install the old [yeoman package from npm](https://npmjs.org/package/yeoman), but it is completely unsupported by now.

Comment: Actually, it is currently not possible to install the old yeoman package from npm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504342/yeoman-wont-install-because-of-406-for-0-9-5-tar-gz