# Yeoman won't install because of 406 for 0.9.5.tar.gz

Tags: npm, yeoman

I tried `npm install yeoman` in linux mint 17 today and get the following error:

```
npm http 406 http://github.com/yeoman/generators/archive/0.9.5.tar.gz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://github.com/yeoman/generators/archive/0.9.5.tar.gz
npm ERR! Error: 406 Not Acceptable
npm ERR!   etc
```

It was working last time I installed a few weeks ago. This is a deal breaker for me today as I need this package.

My npm version is 1.3.10

Any ideas?

Comment: What were you trying to install? Thats not a valid path for any generator.

Comment: I had this same issue. npm 1.4.28, node 0.10.32, yeoman 0.9.6

Comment: The same happens on OSX when running npm install -g yeoman, regardless of node version (tried 0.8, 0.10, 0.11)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to fix this today. Previously, I believe that Yeoman was installed with `npm install -g yeoman`. Apparently, that has been deprecated. I was able to successfully install yeoman with npm 1.4.28 and node 0.10.32 by running `sudo npm install -g yo`. I found the answer by taking a look at their homepage again: http://yeoman.io/.

Comment: This answer only says how to install the "yo" yeoman package. Installing the legacy "yeoman" package is required so that legacy Yeoman-based software can be built.